# Spring Autowired service is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have RestController class that calls Presenter to get some data.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="notes/api")
public class NotesRestController {

private GetAllNotesPresenter getAllNotesPresenter;

@RequestMapping(value="/all")
public List<Note> getAll(){
    getAllNotesPresenter = new GetAllNotesPresenterImpl();
    return getAllNotesPresenter.getAll();
}
```

}

Inside Presenter class I call DataSource (not Spring Repository, just DAO class).

```
public class GetAllNotesPresenterImpl implements GetAllNotesPresenter {

private NotesDataSource dataSource;
private NotesRepository repository;

public GetAllNotesPresenterImpl(){

    dataSource = new DatabaseDataSource();
    repository = new NotesRepositoryImpl(dataSource);
}
@Override
public List<Note> getAll() {
    return repository.getAll();
}
```

}

This is my Repository class, it is not Spring Repository, it just DAO class.

```
public class NotesRepositoryImpl implements NotesRepository {

private NotesDataSource dataSource;

public NotesRepositoryImpl(NotesDataSource dataSource){
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@Override
public List<Note> getAll() {
    return dataSource.getAll();
}
```

}

This is my Service class:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class NotesServiceImpl implements NotesService {

@Autowired
private NotesJpaRepository repository;

@Override
public List<NoteJpa> getAll() {
    return repository.findAll();
}
```

}

Inside DataSource class I want to do @Autowire of Spring service, but I get **null pointer exception.** Service is always null.

```
@Component
public class DatabaseDataSource implements NotesDataSource {

@Autowired
private NotesService notesService;

public DatabaseDataSource(){
}

@Override
public List<Note> getAll() {
    return notesService.getAll();
}
```

}

Comment: If the code above is correct I guess that the `NotesService` will never get constructed (and throw an exception before) because it is expecting a `NotesJpaRepository` that you either not mention or is not a bean. If this should be the implementation of `NotesRepository` it has to be instantiated and exposed as a bean.

Comment: Do you have @Service annotation in "NotesService" interface ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you have annotated the `DatabaseDataSource` as `@Component`, you are not injecting, and thus using it as Spring Bean along the way. You simply create it by hand:

```
public GetAllNotesPresenterImpl(){

    dataSource = new DatabaseDataSource();
    repository = new NotesRepositoryImpl(dataSource);
}
```

In order to take advantage of injection of this bean:

```
@Autowired
private NotesService notesService;
```

you would need to use Spring injection starting from the top (this is only one of the ways you can go about it):

**1)** Inject the dataSource in the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="notes/api")
public class NotesRestController {

private GetAllNotesPresenter getAllNotesPresenter;

@Autowired
private NotesDataSource dataSource;

@RequestMapping(value="/all")
public List<Note> getAll(){
    getAllNotesPresenter = new GetAllNotesPresenterImpl(dataSource);
    return getAllNotesPresenter.getAll();
}
```

**2)** Change the constructor of the `GetAllNotesPresenterImpl`:

```
public GetAllNotesPresenterImpl(NotesDataSource dataSource){

    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    repository = new NotesRepositoryImpl(dataSource);
}
```

Other option would be to make `GetAllNotesPresenterImpl` and `NotesRepositoryImpl` as spring beans and inject dataSource in the `NotesRepositoryImpl` directly. The final call is up to you.

Comment: Yeah, this works :) I need some explanation. What would happen if I had multiple implementations of NotesDataSource. Currently I only have DatabaseDataSource that implement that NotesDataSoruce interfece that inject  inside my RestController class.

Comment: You would use @Qualifier annotation to specify which implementation you explicitly would want to use for the injection.

Comment: Thanks! If you want, you can add that, maybe with example, because a lot of people search for this kind of question. It will maybe be useful to someone.

Comment: Can you also write how to implement other option that you mentioned? I tried but failed. Thanks

Comment: I would just pollute the post with too much stuff. The general idea is to make beans out of the other classes using `@Service` for example. Thanks to that you would not need to inject the dataSource into the controller but directly into the repository without the need to pass it though so many layers.

Comment: So, I should annotate NotesRepostioryImpl as Service?

Comment: i would use @Repository for that